# Headers are not coming in custom email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, logo

I have added the logo image in 
`Content->Configuration->My custom theme Edit->Transactional Emails->Logo` but it goes to 404.

I gave full permission too but Logo image goes to 404.So in email template image is not coming. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is a Magento bug.

You can temporary fix

You can create the folder yourself `pub/media/email/logo/` and then upload the same image to that folder. if you copy from

```
pub/media/logo/default/logo_1.png
```

the destination directory structure should look like

```
pub/media/email/logo/default/logo_1.png
```

There is a fix but it has not been released to the stable release of Magento 2 yet:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/23103c03c527fe1ed3e1a3be691436818b7963fe#diff-6b96f29ad945c7cea90267bd4f533218L12